# Why doesn't it return the JSON as defined in my Mongoose schema definition when I run the POST request?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am having issues running POST request on Postman. When I run a POST request, it only sends back part of a schema defined in my model. I want the whole JSON back defined in my Mongoose schema definition. Here is the code:

**Model:**

```
'use strict';

//*******************
//Dependencies
//*******************
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema  = mongoose.Schema; //attach Schema method on the mongoose object

//Create a new Schema
var rankingsSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

  overall: Number,
  state: String,
  workforce: Number,
  costOfDoingBusiness: Number,
  infrastructure: Number,
  economy: Number,
  qualityOfLife: Number,
  technologyAndInnovation: Number,
  education: Number,
  business: Number,
  costOfLiving: Number,
  accessToCapital: Number

});

//Export the Schema model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Rankings', rankingsSchema);
```

**Controller**

```
var Rankings = require('../models/Rankings');

module.exports = {

//Create endpoint /api/states for POST
  post: function(req, res) {
    //Create a new instance of the State model
    var state = new Rankings();

    //Set the state properties from POST
    state.overall = req.body.overall;
    state.state = req.body.state;
    workforce = req.body.workforce;
    costOfDoingBusiness = req.body.costOfDoingBusiness;
    infrastructure = req.body.infrastructure;
    economy = req.body.economy;
    qualityOfLife = req.body.qualityOfLife;
    technologyAndInnovation = req.body.technologyAndInnovation;
    education = req.body.education;
    business = req.body.business;
    costOfLiving = req.body.costOfLiving;
    accessToCapital = req.body.accessToCapital;

    //Save the data and check for errors
    state.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json ({message: "State Added", data: state});
    });
  },
```

**Server**

```
//*******************
//Start Endpoints
//*******************
router.route('/state')
    .post(RankingsController.post)
    .get(RankingsController.get);
```

**Postman**

[image]

Comment: Add `state` to the callback to save `.save(function(err,state) {`. That way you are sure that the object is the one returned after all validation and conversion is done. You should also just be able to pass in the body rather than assign each property separately i.e `var state = new Rankings(req.body);`

Comment: And actually that is exactly your problem. See how none of the over fields are assigned to `state` as in `workforce = req.body.workforce` as compared to `state.state = req.body.state`. They are not there because you never assigned them.

Comment: Thank you Blake. This makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **Controller**

```
var Rankings = require('../models/Rankings');

module.exports = {

//Create endpoint /api/states for POST
post: function(req, res) {
//Create a new instance of the State model
var state = new Rankings();

//Set the state properties from POST
state.overall = req.body.overall;
state.state = req.body.state;
state.workforce = req.body.workforce;
state.costOfDoingBusiness = req.body.costOfDoingBusiness;
state.infrastructure = req.body.infrastructure;
state.economy = req.body.economy;
state.qualityOfLife = req.body.qualityOfLife;
state.technologyAndInnovation = req.body.technologyAndInnovation;
state.education = req.body.education;
state.business = req.body.business;
state.costOfLiving = req.body.costOfLiving;
state.accessToCapital = req.body.accessToCapital;

//Save the data and check for errors
state.save(function(err) {
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json ({message: "State Added", data: state});
});
},
```

You were missing `state.` before each fields you wanted to add in database so you were just assigning variables.
But I don't know if this really adds your data in database if not use :

```
var Rankings = require('../models/Rankings');
module.exports = {

//Create endpoint /api/states for POST
   post: function(req, res) {

//Create a new instance of the State model

     var state = new Rankings({
         overall: req.body.overall,
         state: req.body.state,
         workforce: req.body.workforce,
         costOfDoingBusiness: req.body.costOfDoingBusiness,
         infrastructure: req.body.infrastructure,
         economy: req.body.economy,
         qualityOfLife: req.body.qualityOfLife,
         technologyAndInnovation: req.body.technologyAndInnovation,
         education: req.body.education,
         business: req.body.business,
         costOfLiving: req.body.costOfLiving,
         accessToCapital: req.body.accessToCapital
     });

//Save the data and check for errors
state.save(function(err, state) {
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json ({message: "State Added", data: state});
});
},
```

As [@Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275) said it's better to add `state` to your `.save(function(err))` to be sure that's the good data that is returned

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!